# How to reset the selectedIndex to 0 for bootstrap selectionbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I reset the selectbox selectedIndex to 0? It works with normal selectboxes, but doesn't works in bootstrap modern selecboxes developed by bootstrap.js

My code HTML :

```
    <select id="profile_ids" class="input-xlarge" data-rel="chosen">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="test_ids" class="input-xlarge" data-rel="chosen">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" class="btn" name="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" onclick="reset_value()"/>
```

Javascript :

```
    function reset_value()
    {
      $('#reset').click(function(){
          $('#profile_ids option[value="0"]').attr('selected','selected');
      });

      $('#reset').click(function(){
          $('#test_ids option[value="0"]').attr('selected','selected');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to reset is:

```
$('[data-rel="chosen"],[rel="chosen"]').chosen();

$('[data-rel="chosen"],[rel="chosen"]').val('').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#profile_ids option').removeAttr('selected');
$('#profile_ids option[value="0"]').attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first option by using `:first`, see [exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/yXGhh/2/)